# Can't find the file "create-multi-platform-projects.py"

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-android, cocosbuilder

I downloaded the sdk (3.0a1). According to [cocos2d-x guide](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/How_to_create_a_multi-platform_project_in_one_command_line), I have to run the `create-multi-platform-projects.py` command in order to create a project, but the script doesn't exist in the package I have downloaded.

The guide says

```
Note: These instructions are only valid for cocos2d-x v3.0-alpha0 or newer
```

So I suppose that I have downloaded the right package (windows 8.0 64bit).

Comment: Are you sure your using cocos2d-x not cocos2d for iphone? If your using cocos2d-x. This script is under `tools/project-creator/`

Answer (score 4):

The script has been moved to tools/project-creator/ and renamed to create_project.py. You can use the script the same way like

`./create_project.py -p MyGame123 -k com.MyCompany.AwesomeGame -l cpp`